# TCP Server : "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted."

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, port, tcplistener

I have a TCP server (implemented as a windows service) for listening to GPS devices in a vehicle tracking application, after random period of time from its operation I got the following error : "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted." While I am sure that I am closing every socket after using it. so can anyone tell me what is the problem here I have the  MaxUserPort value in windows server 2008 registry with (65534) and the TCPTimeWaitDelay value with (30 seconds) ?

Here is the code:
 1) The Main Thread :

```
 private void MainThread() {
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(0, this.port);

        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
        // Addedd on [20/03/2012] by Sherif Mosaad for handling socket exceptions ...
        //listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, (int)1);

        try {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (active) {
                mainDone.Reset();

                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),listener);

                while (active)
                    if (mainDone.WaitOne(100, true))
                        break;
            }
            listener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            listener.Close();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (OnError != null)
                OnError(this, e.ToString());
            LogManager.LogError(e, "TCPSimpleServer MainThread"); 
        }
    }
```

2) The AcceptCallback handler:

```
private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        mainDone.Set();

        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = null;
        try
        {
            handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
        }
        catch 
        {
            try
            {
                listener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                listener.Close();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
            catch { return; }
        }

        if (OnConnect != null)
            OnConnect(this, handler);

        StateObject state = new StateObject();

        state.workSocket = handler;
        state.endPoint = (IPEndPoint)handler.RemoteEndPoint;
        stateObjectDictionary.Add(state, state.workSocket);
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }
```

3) The ReadCallback Handler:

```
 private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        String content = String.Empty;
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        int bytesRead = 0;
        try
        {
            bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Connection closed by client
            if (OnDisconnect != null)
                OnDisconnect(this, state.endPoint);
            return;
        }

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            if (OnDataAvailable != null)
                OnDataAvailable(this, handler, data);
            try
            {
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Connection closed by client
                if (OnDisconnect != null)
                    OnDisconnect(this, state.endPoint);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Connection closed by peer
            if (OnDisconnect != null)
                OnDisconnect(this, state.endPoint);
        }
    }
```

Finally the state object :

```
public class StateObject
    {
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        public IPEndPoint endPoint;
    }
```

Any help please?

Comment: Does it happen to occur after an exception in your first block of code? You should probably be cleaning up your listener in a finally block rather than inside the try itself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a race condition. You call `mainDone.Set` which allows another thread to proceed to `BeginAccept` while the current thread moves towards `EndAccept`. Which will get there first? If you start accepting before finishing the previous accept, I suspect this error might pop up.

Fix? You need to set `mainDone` event *after* you call `EndAccept`

Even better, follow a simpler pattern without synchronization primitives. I outline one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4001421/14357).